# Algoritmo de ordenação, Stream Java

Tags: java, algoritmo

Ao trabalhar com Stream atualmente uso o método sorted para ordenar, exemplo:

```
    Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(3, 2, 1);
    stream.sorted(); // saida será 123
```

Qual o algoritmo de ordenação desse método?

Tem maneiras mais eficientes de ordenar usando Stream?

Comment: Provavelmente é o TimSort que é usado, mas não tenho como garantir essa informação

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Qual o algoritmo de ordenação desse método?

Estou no Java 11.

Primeiro, vejamos como o método `sorted()` é declarado na interface `Stream`:

```
Stream<T> sorted();
```

Ok, isso não nos ajuda. Ele é um método abstrato sem implementação default. Então, para achar a implementação, vejamos o código do `Stream.of(...)`:

```
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs") // Creating a stream from an array is safe
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T... values) {
    return Arrays.stream(values);
}
```

Agora, o código do `Arrays.stream(...)`:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(T[] array) {
    return stream(array, 0, array.length);
}
```

E depois:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(T[] array, int startInclusive, int endExclusive) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(array, startInclusive, endExclusive), false);
}
```

Observe que os valores agora estão armazenados em um `Spliterator`.

Agora o `StreamSupport.stream(...)`:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Spliterator<T> spliterator, boolean parallel) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(spliterator);
    return new ReferencePipeline.Head<>(spliterator,
                                        StreamOpFlag.fromCharacteristics(spliterator),
                                        parallel);
}
```

A classe `java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline` não é uma classe pública, mas o seu código ainda assim pode facilmente ser visto dentro da JDK:

```
abstract class ReferencePipeline<P_IN, P_OUT>
        extends AbstractPipeline<P_IN, P_OUT, Stream<P_OUT>>
        implements Stream<P_OUT>  {
```

Então, vamos ver a classe interna `Head`, que é enfim a implementação de `Stream` que procuramos:

```
static class Head<E_IN, E_OUT> extends ReferencePipeline<E_IN, E_OUT> {
```

A classe interna `Head` herda da classe externa `ReferencePipeline` e não sobrescreve o método `sorted`. Então, olhemos na superclasse (`ReferencePipeline`):

```
@Override
public final Stream<P_OUT> sorted() {
    return SortedOps.makeRef(this);
}
```

A classe `SortedOps` também não é pública. Vejamos que método é esse `makeRef`:

```
static <T> Stream<T> makeRef(AbstractPipeline<?, T, ?> upstream) {
    return new OfRef<>(upstream);
}
```

A classe `OfRef` é interna à `SortedOps`:

```
private static final class OfRef<T> extends ReferencePipeline.StatefulOp<T, T> {
    /**
     * Comparator used for sorting
     */
    private final boolean isNaturalSort;
    private final Comparator<? super T> comparator;

    /**
     * Sort using natural order of {@literal <T>} which must be
     * {@code Comparable}.
     */
    OfRef(AbstractPipeline<?, T, ?> upstream) {
        super(upstream, StreamShape.REFERENCE,
              StreamOpFlag.IS_ORDERED | StreamOpFlag.IS_SORTED);
        this.isNaturalSort = true;
        // Will throw CCE when we try to sort if T is not Comparable
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Comparator<? super T> comp = (Comparator<? super T>) Comparator.naturalOrder();
        this.comparator = comp;
    }

    /**
     * Sort using the provided comparator.
     *
     * @param comparator The comparator to be used to evaluate ordering.
     */
    OfRef(AbstractPipeline<?, T, ?> upstream, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        super(upstream, StreamShape.REFERENCE,
              StreamOpFlag.IS_ORDERED | StreamOpFlag.NOT_SORTED);
        this.isNaturalSort = false;
        this.comparator = Objects.requireNonNull(comparator);
    }

    @Override
    public Sink<T> opWrapSink(int flags, Sink<T> sink) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(sink);

        // If the input is already naturally sorted and this operation
        // also naturally sorted then this is a no-op
        if (StreamOpFlag.SORTED.isKnown(flags) && isNaturalSort)
            return sink;
        else if (StreamOpFlag.SIZED.isKnown(flags))
            return new SizedRefSortingSink<>(sink, comparator);
        else
            return new RefSortingSink<>(sink, comparator);
    }

    @Override
    public <P_IN> Node<T> opEvaluateParallel(PipelineHelper<T> helper,
                                             Spliterator<P_IN> spliterator,
                                             IntFunction<T[]> generator) {
        // If the input is already naturally sorted and this operation
        // naturally sorts then collect the output
        if (StreamOpFlag.SORTED.isKnown(helper.getStreamAndOpFlags()) && isNaturalSort) {
            return helper.evaluate(spliterator, false, generator);
        }
        else {
            // @@@ Weak two-pass parallel implementation; parallel collect, parallel sort
            T[] flattenedData = helper.evaluate(spliterator, true, generator).asArray(generator);
            Arrays.parallelSort(flattenedData, comparator);
            return Nodes.node(flattenedData);
        }
    }
}
```

Note o `Arrays.parallelSort(flattenedData, comparator);`. É aqui que alguma ordenação está sendo feita:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> void parallelSort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> cmp) {
    if (cmp == null)
        cmp = NaturalOrder.INSTANCE;
    int n = a.length, p, g;
    if (n <= MIN_ARRAY_SORT_GRAN ||
        (p = ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism()) == 1)
        TimSort.sort(a, 0, n, cmp, null, 0, 0);
    else
        new ArraysParallelSortHelpers.FJObject.Sorter<>
            (null, a,
             (T[])Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), n),
             0, n, 0, ((g = n / (p << 2)) <= MIN_ARRAY_SORT_GRAN) ?
             MIN_ARRAY_SORT_GRAN : g, cmp).invoke();
}
```

E então temos a linha `TimSort.sort(a, 0, n, cmp, null, 0, 0);` denunciando que o algoritmo usado é o TimSort em alguns casos (no caso do `if`). Se isso cair no `else`, vejamos esse `ArraysParallelSortHelpers.FJObject.Sorter`:

```
static final class FJObject {
    static final class Sorter<T> extends CountedCompleter<Void> {
        static final long serialVersionUID = 2446542900576103244L;
        final T[] a, w;
        final int base, size, wbase, gran;
        Comparator<? super T> comparator;
        Sorter(CountedCompleter<?> par, T[] a, T[] w, int base, int size,
               int wbase, int gran,
               Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
            super(par);
            this.a = a; this.w = w; this.base = base; this.size = size;
            this.wbase = wbase; this.gran = gran;
            this.comparator = comparator;
        }
        public final void compute() {
            CountedCompleter<?> s = this;
            Comparator<? super T> c = this.comparator;
            T[] a = this.a, w = this.w; // localize all params
            int b = this.base, n = this.size, wb = this.wbase, g = this.gran;
            while (n > g) {
                int h = n >>> 1, q = h >>> 1, u = h + q; // quartiles
                Relay fc = new Relay(new Merger<>(s, w, a, wb, h,
                                                  wb+h, n-h, b, g, c));
                Relay rc = new Relay(new Merger<>(fc, a, w, b+h, q,
                                                  b+u, n-u, wb+h, g, c));
                new Sorter<>(rc, a, w, b+u, n-u, wb+u, g, c).fork();
                new Sorter<>(rc, a, w, b+h, q, wb+h, g, c).fork();;
                Relay bc = new Relay(new Merger<>(fc, a, w, b, q,
                                                  b+q, h-q, wb, g, c));
                new Sorter<>(bc, a, w, b+q, h-q, wb+q, g, c).fork();
                s = new EmptyCompleter(bc);
                n = q;
            }
            TimSort.sort(a, b, b + n, c, w, wb, n);
            s.tryComplete();
        }
    }
```

E novamente, vemos o `TimSort.sort(a, b, b + n, c, w, wb, n);` lá.

Conclusão: O algoritmo usado é o [TimSort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

> Tem maneiras mais eficientes de ordenar usando Stream?

Isso depende muito da distribuição dos dados. Sem assumir nada sobre a distribuição dos dados, o algoritmo TimSort é um excelente algoritmo estável, com tempo de processamento **Θ(n log n)** e que tende a bater outros algoritmos que também são **Θ(n log n)**. O TimSort é baseado no MergeSort, mas ele tenta se aproveitar de ordenamentos parciais dos dados sempre que possível para otimizar algumas coisas e pode seletivamente utilizar o InsertionSort em determinadas partes pequenas onde isso seria mais rápido que o MergeSort. Esse algoritmo também aproveita-se de várias outras possíveis otimizações.

Dito isso, é difícil haver uma forma mais eficiente de ordenar um `Stream` **qualquer** do que desse modo que serve para o **caso geral**. É difícil encontrar algum algoritmo de ordenação que possa bater o TimSort no caso geral. Além disso, a implementação dada ainda tenta paralelizar essa aplicação do TimSort se o array for grande o suficiente (é o que ocorre no `ArraysParallelSortHelpers.FJObject.Sorter`) para tentar obter um desempenho ainda melhor.

No entanto, se o seu `Stream` não for um `Stream` qualquer e sim algo que você saiba de antemão que tenha uma determinada estrutura ou ordenação específica da qual você pode tirar proveito para uma ordenação melhor, então nesses **casos específicos**, uma outra forma de ordenação melhor pode ser possível. Mas aí, cada caso é um caso.